# Workaround to template specialization

Tags: c#

**Abstract Base Class**

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Method<T>(T args) { }
}
```

**Derived Class** *several of these exist, each with a replacement for **T***

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Method<int>(int args) { }
}
```

Now, I know this isn't supported, but I need it because somewhere else in my code

```
class AnotherBaseClass<T, E>
    where E : Base
{
    E e;  // Will be actually one of the derived classes
    T t;  // Simple types like string or int
    
    // I want this to work basically
    public void Func()
    {
        e.Method(t);
    }
}
```

*this* is going on.

What is the easiest solution to this? If I am able to do this, it will save me from writing a lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine with making `Base` a generic class, this is how:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
     public abstract void Method(T args);
}

class Derived : Base<int>
{
    public override void Method(int args) {}
}

class AnotherBaseClass<T, E>
    where E : Base<T>
{
    E e;
    T t;

    public void Func()
    {
        e.Method(t);
    }
}
```

If you need `Base` to not be generic, you can add this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public void Method<T>(T args)
    {
        var genericSelf = this as Base<T>;
        genericSelf.Method(args);
    }
}
```

and make `Base<T>` inherit `Base` and ensure your concrete classes always derive `Base<T>` and never `Base` directly.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to write that I tried the first method (making ``Base`` a generic class), but it doesn't work when I want to use ``Base`` as a function argument for e.g. ``public void Fn(Base base)``. With the 2nd method I can use ``Base`` for function arguments and ``Base<T>`` for subclasses, right?

Comment: You must subclass `Base<T>` for concrete classes as I said, don't derive `Base`` directly or else the `this as Base<T>` will return null.

Comment: Yes I am using ``Base<T>`` for all concrete sealed classes and `Base` is just used for the function signature as I could not do ``public void Fn(Base<T> base)``. It gave compile errors.

Comment: you need to write `public void Fn<T>(Base<T> base)` for it to compile

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what problem you're sovling but under .Net 5 what you have in your question works as is...

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Method<T>(T args);
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Method<T>(T args)
    {
        Console.Write($"{nameof(Derived)}.Method<{typeof(T)}>({args})");
    }
}

class AnotherBaseClass<T, E> where E : Base
{
    readonly E e;
    readonly T t;

    public AnotherBaseClass(T t, E e)
    {
        this.e = e;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void Func()
    {
        e.Method(t);
    }
}
```

Run like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();

        var another = new AnotherBaseClass<int,Derived>(5, d);

        another.Func();
    }
```

Produces:  "Derived.Method<System.Int32>(5)"

Comment: The question was about having a derived class with a non-generic method but rather a method implemented for a specific type, e.g. int

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.5, and yeah as @EldarS mentioned, this is not the solution I wanted

Comment: @EldarS this is literally what he said he was trying to do in his question.  The code is not mine, it's his.